# Can't get find(...).count(...) to count my items

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Why doesn't the following count call work? I know there is a "My testlist" in the collection, but count is always 0. This part of my integration test validation, names are unique in my database.

```
db.collection('lists', function(err, collection) {
 collection.find({name: "My testlist"}).count(function(err, count) {
  console.log("err: " + err + ", count: " + count)
  assert.equal(1, count)
 })
})
```

I am using the mongodb native driver in NodeJS.

Comment: Are you sure it is that exact case "My testlist"? If you run it without the count do you get a cursor with the document?

Comment: Hmm... found the problem, thank you for pointing me at the right direction. It wasn't saved as I though it had been.